# Dynamic form to CSV file with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I would like to take the form input from each row in my table (**oldc, newc, skey**) and implant them as a row in a CSV file.
As far as I know they are already in an array? So is there a simple way I can use a *foreach loop* **(my current loop is broken)** in my PHP?

I dont know much about programming, so clear answers are appreciated.
Thanks.

**Index.html**

```
<form class="form-inline" id="main-form" action="process.php" method="post"> 
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input required name="username" class="form-control" type="text" value="a" maxlength="4" placeholder="Enter name(Max 4 Characters)"> 
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Save to server</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-dark table-striped table order-list">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input  name='oldc[]' type="text" class="form-control" value="b" maxlength='17' required placeholder='W7 SN' /></td>
                        <td><input  name='newc[]' type="text" class="form-control" value="c" maxlength='17' required placeholder='W10 SN' /></td>
                        <td><input  name='skey[]' type="text" class="form-control" value="d" maxlength='10' required placeholder='Security Key' /></td>
                        <td><button name='del'  type="button" class="btn btn-danger invisible" >Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

**Scripts.js**

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var cols = "";


    cols += '<td><input type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="W7 SN"        name="oldc[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="W10 SN"       name="newc[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
    cols += '<td><input type="text"   class="form-control" placeholder="Security Key" name="skey[]' + counter + '"/></td>';

    cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger"           value="Delete"></td>';
    newRow.append(cols);
    $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    counter++;
    i++;

});
```

**process.php**

```
$oldc = $_POST["oldc"];
$newc = $_POST["newc"];
$skey = $_POST["skey"];
$header = 'W7 SN, W10 SN, Security Key';
$data = $header . "\n" . $oldc . "," . $newc . "," . $skey . "\n";

$myfile = fopen($location, 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");

foreach ($data as $row){
fputcsv($myfile, $row }
);


fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: `$data` is not an array, it's just a string.

Comment: You say "I dont know much about programming".  I'd suggest that you take the time now to learn.  There's honestly too much wrong or missing here for me to be able to make this right.

Comment: I have looked up as many examples as I could (including PHP arrays) for many days, but could not find a similar code.  Nigel's snippet has fixed my issue, however I am curious as to what is "wrong" with the code though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data being passed in are in themselves arrays, you can't just add them together somehow and then hope that `fputcsv` will sort them out.

What I've done is to assume that your input will have an array of oldc, newc and skey values coming in from the form.  The code loops over the oldc values and picks out the corresponding value from each of the other arrays...

```
$oldc = $_POST["oldc"];
$newc = $_POST["newc"];
$skey = $_POST["skey"];
$header = 'W7 SN, W10 SN, Security Key';
$header = explode(",", $header);

$myfile = fopen($location, 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");
fputcsv($myfile, $header );
foreach ($oldc as $key => $value){
    $row = [ $value, $newc[$key], $skey[$key]];

    fputcsv($myfile, $row);
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code.

- There is syntax error in your code. `)` is missing near `}`
- `$data` is not array.

Replace

```
$header = 'W7 SN, W10 SN, Security Key';
$data = $header . "\n" . $oldc . "," . $newc . "," . $skey . "\n";
```

with following

```
$header = 'W7 SN, W10 SN, Security Key';
$data = array(
        'W7 SN'=> $oldc,
        'W10 SN'=> $newc,
        'Security Key'=>$skey
       );


fputcsv($myfile, array('W7 SN', 'W10 SN', 'Security Key'));

// put foreach here
```

Comment: Can't speak for the person who downvoted - but... If this is the only problem (and it isn't) then you should vote to close the question as a 'a simple typographical error.'

Comment: Also, don't post an incomplete answer just to be first.  If you know that you need to add more, don't post until you're ready to address all of the issues.  FYI, you still have a syntax error in that code.

Comment: @NigelRen there are multiple issues, I have update my answer